# df[~df.id.isin not dropping anything from the original df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I was trying to drop the rows with id equals anything in the `ND_Before0_Opioid.id.unique()` list with the following code:

```py
ND = data[~data.id.isin([ND_Before0_Opioid.id.unique()])]
```

But nothing was changed, ND is still exactly the same with original data

Comment: That would be expected if the columns have different `dtypes`, for example. There's nowhere near enough info here to be sure, you need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

roganjosh comment is on point. The .isin does't work if dtypes of both lists aren't the same.

Try this:

```
ND = data[~data.id.astype(int).isin(ND_Before0_Opioid.id.astype(int).unique())]
```